# How to make a stable Durandal router URL

Tags: html, single-page-application, durandal, sammy.js

I'm using  durandal to make a SPA website. Thing is, the URL not not stable everytime.

I make the login page outsite of SPA, so after login, I use `RedirectToAction` of MVC3 to redirect to SPA index.

Sometimes the URL is `http://localhost/Student/Home/Index#/` while sometimes it's `http://localhost/Student/Home/Index/#/`

At first I think this is not a big deal, but right now this really pissed me off because I have to use images outside of durandal folder.

```
- durandal folder
- Content/Images folder
```

When I call from a SPA view like this:

```
<img src="../Content/Images/img_chart.png" alt=""/>
```

I only work when the URL is `Index#/` not when the URL is `Index/#/`

How can I make a URL stable everytime? This seem to be a problem of SammyJS I suppose.

Comment: What is `RedirectToAction` doing and what does `router.map` look like.? You might consider using relative links from the root instead `src="/Student/Home/Content/Images/img_chart.png" alt=""/>`?

Comment: Please post your login code with the RedirectToAction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the image src via a class defined in a css file. Once you do that, you can use the image location relative to your css location.

```
<div><img class="loading" /></div>
```

the class for "loading" can be defined in your base css. I have it defined in my layout.css

```
.loading
{
     content:url('images/ajax-loader.gif');
}
```

Now, the layout.css mentioned uses its own location to form the relative path to the images folder and it all works.

```
|-[]Images
   |-ajax-loader.gif
|-[]SomeotherFolder
|-layout.css
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using content:url for img elements is not supported accordingly to w3c and does not work in FFX. (img elemenents MUST have src attribute)